# Wordpress misterious link error, crazy redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect

i have a strange bug on my wordpress. I installed wordpress on a subdomain. Everything was ok at first, but now if i try to access my page cn.adep.ro i get redirected to http://www.cn.adep.ro/cn/cn/cn/cn/cn/cn/cn/cn/cn/cn/cn/. I have another wordpress on a different subdomain and that one works (en.adep.ro). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a redirect Loop somewhere in your site. Look into the theme or plugin files.